# Slider jQuery UI method after slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have the next problem. I use a slider of jQueryUI and it works perfectly but what I would like to do is to do stuff when I move the slider and I release the mouse.

The problem is that if it has 5 values, from 0 to 4, if I move from 0 to the 4, it loads a function 4 times.

```
        $('#sliderTime').slider({
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            value:1,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                var value = ui.value;               
                dostuff(value);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var value = ui.value;               
    dostuff(value);
}
```

to

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
    var value = ui.value;               
    dostuff(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you use `"change"` event instead of `"stop"`.